# Integrating private server hosted rhodecode into slack

Tags: slack-api, slack, rhodecode

I would like to add an integration for a privately hosted rhodecode server into slack. There are numerous tutorials on how to do this while using rhodecode enterprise but we aren't using the enterprise version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install rcextensions, and just enable slack plugin there. It posts messages to given channel about pushed commits, also there's a slack plugin that could be configured to notify about open/closed/merged pull requests.

You can drop us an email to support@rhodecode.com to help you configure the slack integration.

Comment: in 4.4.X there is a ootb slack integration that allows to simply add your channel and the incoming-webhook url, and then it just works :)